# Cannot unlock bootloader of my OnePlus 2 with oem unlock

Tags: htc-desire, fastboot, bootloader, htc, bootloader-lock

I want to flash my *OnePlus 2*, as it's stuck on the boot logo. For this, I first need to unlock the bootloader, but I can't: the adb command tells me I have to check "oem unlock" in the phone settings. I can't boot in normal mode to do so (as said, my phone is stuck on boot logo).

Is there any way to unlock the boot loader for my phone?

Answer (score 0):

No... It is a safeguard in newer Android versions. Even if you have the correct unlock token, you must have the option turned on in Developer Options before attempting to unlock the bootloader or it will not be allowed. This is a nearly foolproof system, there is no know software based way around it.

Comment: my phone is oneplus 2 stuck at logo and i want to falsh it

Comment: Flash the factory image... Then enable OEM unlock in Developer Options

Comment: there is no way to flash factory image without unlocking boot

Comment: @AbdouDélécoo Factory images do not require the bootloader to be unlocked, they are digitally signed and can be flashed via stock recovery

Comment: i searsh,it requir bootloader to be unlocked :)

Comment: Umm... so your telling me using the official procedure with the factory Qualcom flashing tool and factory image requires the bootloader to be unlocked? That makes ZERO sense. http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-2/general/guide-official-stock-reset-to-oos-2-2-0-t3290707

Comment: its unbrick method that let you unbrick your phone,but still confuse if other phone like (htc) have like this tool for unbricking

Comment: @AbdouDélécoo no,  for HTC you need the RUU file and run that